# How to add a Not Exists clause to this RegEx?

Tags: find, regular-expression

I'm trying to traverse a directory and look for the following 2 conditions:

1. All files that end in .js
2. All files that end in .js but do **not** end with _test.js

I have a RegEx that satisfies #1 above which is as follows:

```
find . -iregex '.*\.\(js\)' -printf '"%p",\n'
```

I'm struggling with how to add the condition for #2 above. RegEx is an area I'm weak and I'm not sure I'm looking at the right documentation to compose a RegEx that satisfies both conditions.

I tried the following to try and prevent files with `_test` but it didn't work and still returns all of the files:

```
find . -iregex '.*\.\(js\)' -not -iregex '^(?!.*_test.*$)' -printf '"%p",\n'
```

How can I modify the above working RegEx statement to also satisfy the 2nd requirement please?

Comment: why do you need a regex ? `-iname "*.js" -not -iname "*_test.js"` should work fine.

Comment: @pLumo - Yeah as I mentioned, this isn't my area of expertise, so I'm not surprised my method might have been the long way to do it. I tried what you provided and it worked well. If you want to repost as a qualified answer, and why it's better I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand your regex, why you have all these brackets and a doubled negation (`-not` and `(?!...)`). The latter won't work anyways as long as you don't enable PCRE regex (see `-regextype` option).

This simple regex would work:

```
find . -type f -iregex ".*\.js" -not -iregex ".*_test\.js"
```

But, for your task you don't need any regex, simple filename matching is enough:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.js" -not -iname "*_test.js"
```